# How to add a photo to my profile?

Tags: support

I was unable to find the answer to the following question: How do I add a picture of myself to my profile (account) as, say, Peter K did?

Answer (score 2):

Rick you have to use the (not very obvious) tabs on your profile page and select the **Edit Profile & Settings** "tab".

[image]

Comment: Also, be sure to save your changes on the bottom of the page. I've neglected to do that step and the change doesn't actually stick in that case.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like it worked! You're welcome! :-)